# How to delete an entire row if a specific column contains a zero?

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I need to delete the rows which contains
0 value in column number 5.

Before:

```
1QWO     10      5     45    100    7.5
1R0R      6      3     15    100    8.5
1R5M      4      0      6      0    6.5
1R8S      4      0      6      0      6
1R9L      2      1      1    100    6.3
1RG8      6      0     15      0    5.8
1RJU     10      0     45      0    7.2
1RKI     12      6     66    100    4.6
```

After:

```
1QWO     10      5     45    100    7.5
1R0R      6      3     15    100    8.5
1R9L      2      1      1    100    6.3
1RKI     12      6     66    100    4.6
```

Any one liner will be very helpful.

I know:

```
sed '/0/d' file_name
```

but above command will delete 0 from all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With portable sed you can do it like this:

```
sed '/\([^ ]\+ \+\)\{4\}0\+ /d'
```

This way you confine checking for zero to the fifth column.

With perl you can use auto-split, notice that you don't need to specify a condition for  `$F[4]` because it is implicit:

```
perl -ane 'print if $F[4]'
```

Output in both cases:

```
1QWO     10      5     45    100    7.5
1R0R      6      3     15    100    8.5
1R9L      2      1      1    100    6.3
1RKI     12      6     66    100    4.6
```

Answer (score 11):

```
awk '$5 != 0'
```

The machine won't let me submit unless I add this extra text.

Answer (score 10):

Even faster:

```
awk '$5' file
```

If the 5th field is not `0` then the condition is evaluated as true - note that `{print $0}` is the default block in `awk` so it can be omitted if this is the only action you want to perform.

Answer (score 7):

This is definately more suited to `awk`:

```
$ awk '$5!=0' file
1QWO     10      5     45    100    7.5
1R0R      6      3     15    100    8.5
1R9L      2      1      1    100    6.3
1RKI     12      6     66    100    4.6
```

But if you really want a `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -r '/\S+\s+{4}0\s+/d' file
1QWO     10      5     45    100    7.5
1R0R      6      3     15    100    8.5
1R9L      2      1      1    100    6.3
1RKI     12      6     66    100    4.6
```